# difference between x*= and x=x*...?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Look at this function:

```
int c(int n,int k) {
    if (n<0 || k<0 || n<k) {
        return 0;
    }
    int c=1,p=n-k,i=1;
    while (n>p) {
        c = c * n/i++; // <<<
        n--;
    }
    return c;
}
```

when I change `c=c*n/i++` to `c*=n/i++` function don't work correctly. for example c(4,2)=4 (=6 true) I traced with:1.i++ 2./ 3.*= and all other possibilities but no answer. why?

edit: this is not my question as people know. I asked why compiler answer `c(4,2)=4` when `c*=n/i++`. I traced `*/++, *++/, /*++, /++*, ++*/, ++/*` but answer is not 4 at all. what is compiler's logic?(sorry for bad English)

Comment: You've named a local variable the same as the enclosing function. Step inside, we need to have a talk....

Comment: I believe there's an extra curly brace there. Careful with your indentation, someone reading the code might quickly think that the code after `return 0` is part of the `if` statement block.

Comment: @jrok: There are languages (Turbo Pascal? VB?) in which the name of a function can be used as the return variable. I.e. the last value assigned is the value returned. C++ of course is not like that at all.

Comment: K&R bracing really is harder to read. :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the case of

```
c = c * n / i++;
```

You *first* multiply `c` and `n`, then divide it by `i`, and lastly `i` is increased.

When you do

```
c *= n / i++;
```

You first to the division and increase of `i`, *then* do the multiplication.

---

In other words:

```
c = c * n / i++;
```

is equal to

```
c = (c * n) / i++;
```

While

```
c *= n / i++;
```

is equal to

```
c = c * (n / i++);
```

Comment: So if you're not sure your co-workers are as proficient in operator precedence as you, only use the compound assignment operators if that's the only operation being performed `;-)`.

Comment: @ar2015 It might, or it might not. The only way is to create a benchmark program, build it with optimizations enabled, compare the generated code through a diassembler, and then run the benchmark to measure (if the generated code differs).

Answer (score 2):

Due to operator precedence (or language grammar if you prefer), the two are:

```
c = ((c * n) / i++);
```

versus

```
c = c * (n / i++);
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a *= E;
```

is equivalent to this:

```
a = a * (E);
```

If you have a complex expression line the following:

```
a *= b + c;
```

Gets translated as:

```
a = a * (b + c);
```

... but not like this:

```
a = a * b + c; // WRONG
```

Therefore, the line:

```
c *= n/i++;
```

Is equivalent as:

```
c = c * (n / i++);
```

Which **for integers** is not the same as:

```
c = c * n / i++;
```